# Vue.js is detected on this page. Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author

Tags: google-chrome, laravel-5, google-chrome-extension, vue.js

[image]

I'm trying to enable [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) in Google Chrome. But I cannot enable it. I'm using vue.js inside the Laravel application.

[image]

My server runs using `php artisan serve` command.

Comment: OK, how do you enable vue.js. Did you install it with Laravel. (Ok I don't know Laravel). However, that would be nice to know

Comment: No, It come as default in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend#writing-javascript

Comment: OK, as I understand do you use npm to manage all scss and javascript packages. Is that right? You may can look into your package.json which version of vue is used. Like it is explained here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds if you using the minified version it is only availble in production mode and no dev tools will work.

Answer (score 43):

I was seeing the error message in this question's title and [this solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/190#issuecomment-329728926) worked for me:

Add `Vue.config.devtools = true` to the file where you create the Vue instance (`main.js` for me).

Note that, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986155/4115031), you need to put the `Vue.config.devtools = true` line before you create your store in order for the Vuex part of the devtools to work.  If you're creating your Vuex store in a separate file (e.g. `store.js`), you may need to have the `Vue.config.devtools = true` line in both your `main.js` file as well as the `store.js` file.

Below is what the changes looked like in my project:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

1. If the page uses a production/minified build of Vue.js, devtools
   inspection is disabled by default so the Vue pane won't show up.
2. To make it work for pages opened via file:// protocol, you need to
   check "Allow access to file URLs" for this extension in Chrome's
   extension management panel.
3. I had to restart the chrome, and it worked :-)

Comment: I had to change from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js

Comment: This did not work for me, even with a Chrome restart.

Answer (score 10):

**Updated Aug 2022**
So apparently as @kissu said, the answer below causes **the released code to be an unoptimized one**. This might be different than what you want if you want to check production code while being able to check Vue Dev Tools.

Just be aware of it. Unless you don't mind checking the released code in an unoptimized bundle, then the following script is fine. If you don't like the `Vue.config.devtools` value being static, it might be time to consider `env` variables or something similar.

Here's how to setup [Environtment Variables in Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

---

**Alternative answer for Vue CLI 3.x**
Besides what @NathanWailes has said, this is an alternative which allows the Dev Tools to be available through `scripts` instead of writing it in your main Vue entry (which is usually `main.js` or `index.js`).

You can do this by simply adding this script to `package.json`

```
scripts: {
   "start:dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode=development"
}
```

**Explanation**
This was because `Vue.config.devtools` are set to `false` by default in production mode as said by this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/190). But ***this has a work around,*** simply by using `--mode=development` flag provided in the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build).

Then you can run using `npm run start:dev` and check the file in your `dist/` folder! ;)

Comment: Similar approach when using Vite: "vite build --mode development", as documented here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes

Comment: Sorry, forgot the step 2, adding the run script to my deploy. ::) works like charm.

Comment: Isn't this sending an unoptimized bundle to production? Probably not a good idea.

Comment: @kissu The OP wants to enable Vue Dev Tools, this only answers that question. Now how you use it is another issue. That's why I added a custom script `start:dev`. Nonetheless, this answer was when I used Vue 2. I haven't been using Vue 3 yet. If you have something to add, feel free to add it.

Comment: Nothing related to Vue2 vs 3 and also, even if this one answers the question it's still hiding quite a big quirk. OP not being aware of such impact, is probably not something that he wants. It's like recommending to cut one of your arms with the purpose of loosing weight, yeah it works indeed. Probably not a viable solution overall tho.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kissu. I haven't been in a Vue project for a while, what enhancement do you suggest to this answer? Or maybe if you have any references that refer to this issue it would be great!

Comment: I basically recommend the most official solution aka the most upvoted one here.

Comment: Thanks @kissu. I just remembered what you meant. Hope the updated answer pleases you and the others! 

Answer (score 9):

If your using CDN; make sure your not using a production (minified) build of the library.

*Use:* https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js

*Instead of:* https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.min.js

You might need to do **`Ctrl+Alt+I`** for it to show up the first time. ([Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/62#issuecomment-166890394))

Answer (score 6):

##### `vite build --mode development`

In order to enable Vue devtools for `vite build --mode development` you need this config:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
  ...
  define: {
    __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: mode !== 'production'
  },
}))
```

Comment: This is the solution for Vue 3!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with Vite + Laravel + Inertia.js

Answer (score 2):

You may use the dev version of vue.js. For example get it here: https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.2

Comment: It comes with Laravel 5.4. If you can explain more, it would be nice. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2):

When using Laravel just make sure you run the proper webpack for your environment for development . Running

> npm run watch

should build Vue with debug mode on. Using

> npm run production

minifies Vue for production. This will save you having to remember to toggle the debug mode when building for production.

Answer (score 1):

For me Installing latest Vue dev tools - [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg) and enabling 'Allow access to file URLs' in extension settings resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're running a non-production build of Vue.js. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/62

Answer (score 0):

Just add into vue.config.js:

```html
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

delete package-lock.json, node_modules, run npm i and VueJS Devtool will be working

Answer (score 0):

you could try to set environment variable NODE_ENV to 'development'
(e.g. `set NODE_ENV=development` on Windows or `export NODE_ENV="development"` under Linux)
before launching Vue dev server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for Laravel 9 fresh installation, I forgot to run `sail npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) you can configure your environment directory via [shared options](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envdir). If you change that and have `NODE_ENV` set to `production` you'll receive this message when trying to inspect your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CDN version of Vue, then you need to set the following configuration:

Vue.config.devtools = true;

After running this command, open the browser console and refresh the page. If the Vue DevTools still don't show up, then try clearing the cache in your browser.