# No Vuex store detected in Vue Dev Tools (vue2/vuex3)

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, vuex, vue-devtools

For very specific reasons, I have set the vue dev tools to true in production.

```
Vue.config.devtools = true
```

Am using the following versions:

```
"vue": "^2.5.2"
"vuex": "^3.0.1"
"vuetify": "^1.0.0"
```

While I can see the components and events, the Vuex store is not detected.

I have tried downgrading the vuex version to 2.3.1 and 2.4.x, but it did not help. 
Here's the link I referred to - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/405

Note - The store works well, its just that I am not able to view it in the Vue dev tools.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: You should set `NODE_ENV` to the `development` as well. Use this answer if u don't know how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js

Answer (score 26):

you have to set `Vue.config.devtools = true` before you create the store.

here my store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.config.devtools = true

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  }
})
```

Comment: If you import your store, you need it there as well https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/405#issuecomment-379314711

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure to turn on recording mode in devtools (the red round button).

It was turned off and that actually was the mistake. :-D

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with Vue 3.
Updating the vuex from 4.0.0 to 4.0.2 did resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Update from 4.0.0 to 4.0.2 did indeed solve the problem with the missing vuex in devtools

Answer (score 0):

If Vuex store values is showing undefined it is probably because the values were not **set through mutations**

Comment: Mithsew, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this issue for me was to place the devtools import just before Vue on my `main.js` file:

```js
import devtools from '@vue/devtools';
import Vue from 'vue';
// ...
```

The docs mention this: https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#using-dependency-package

> Make sure you import devtools before Vue, otherwise it might not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, no Vuex will show in my vue devtools. What helped me was:

- in menu (3 dots on the right)select devtools plugins
- from the list that show up choose your vue (in my case "Vue 2")
- uncheck and check again 'enabled'
- close devtools
- refresh your page

Comment: It would be at least beneficial to share some information on which browser you are using so people can determine whether this short guide you shared is valuable to them.

Answer (score 0):

An empty cache refresh did it for me.