# Is displaying web3.currentProvider in console insecure

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, ethereum, web3js

[screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PCw4.png)

in my website i'm using **Laravel** and **VueJS** for developing.

So when is type `web3.currentProvider` in console i can see my provider details. Is this good or bad.

Any way to hide it.

Comment: Is this due to using the dev version of the vue libraries (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781351/vue-js-is-detected-on-this-page-devtools-inspection-is-not-available-because-it)?

Comment: no its not same with npm run production

Comment: I'm not familiar with [tag:web3js] in particular, but presumably that setting is used to make HTTP requests to that URL, right? Those would be visible in the network inspector either way. Generally: anything happening in Javascript in the browser is visible to the owner of said browser.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is visible console the user could see otherwise, because on the client-side the user owns all the information.

There is no reason to hide it.